# Can't find Tor Browser in the bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows

I would like to use Tor via a thumb drive. I have gone thru a youtube video claiming that I have to download Tor bundle and extract the content to a thumb drive. I did follow the instructions, however, I couldn't find the Tor Browser from the bundle.

Can anyone please provide the correct link to download the current Tor bundle with Tor Browser?

Comment: Which platform? Windows, OSX, Linux ?

Comment: Hi I'm using WIndows 8

Comment: Any suggestion TOR users???

Answer (score 1):

Download the bundle from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

After download, run the downloaded exe and point it to your thumbdrive.
Run the shortcut it creates where you unpack it to start the software.

Instructions with screenshots are located here:
https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#windows

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links. I have already been thru those links and I simply can't find the TOR browser or .exe file

Comment: Click the large download button, download the file for windows ( direct link: https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/5.0.6/torbrowser-install-5.0.6_en-US.exe ), run the file, point to the thumb drive during install.

Answer (score -1):

I think I know the problem - let me explain. Recently I helped one person - he actually had **a fake tor.exe** from his bundle installer, so attacks on an official download page **do exist** and so fake Tor distro's too. You should try to use I2P to obtain a Tor through this darknet. They work together pretty good, actually - [here is the official page](https://geti2p.net/en/download) - make sure to verify the signatures!

Comment: Hi Alexey - how did you know the executable was fake?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks it opened a ports described in torrc, but they sent errors + an output was faked, i.e. verbose log to stdout was not going. We used expert bundle and replaced it - and everything started to work properly. It was a forged tor binary, everything else were exactly the same. Smart move, by the way!